# R poisson confidence intervals

Tags: r, poisson, confidence-interval, standard-error

I use poisson regression (`glm()` with `family='poisson'`) and would like to give the answers in the form:

"Each predicted value has an error from the interval [low, high] with probability 0.95".

1. Is it possible to do? If yes, how?
2. I see few ways.

1) Compute residuals and get the low and high values. Which distribution should I use?

2) 
Use function `predict.glm(model, type = 'link', se.fit=TRUE)`.
Compute confidence intervals for normal distribution. Use

```
model$family$linkinv()
```

to figure out low and high values.

I have implemented the second case. The question is how can I give the answers in the form described above?

Comment: Make your example [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1478381) and you will probably get an answer very quickly...

Comment: This appears to be a problem more from a lack of statistical background than from the fact that you are using R. Suggest you request the moderators to migrate to CrossValidated.

Comment: your case #2 is essentially correct: it's not clear what else you need for a complete answer to your question.